# Difficulty calling JavaScript function on click after dynamically generating table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having difficulty making a clickable button in my dynamically generated table that would send data specific to the table cell that was clicked.

My table is generated and modified whenever the user types into the search box with this AJAX call:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#data").keyup(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: "data=" + $("#data").val(),
                url: "search1.php",
                success: function(msg){
                    var output = "";
                    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                        output += '<tr onmouseover=this.style.backgroundColor="#ffff66"; onmouseout=this.style.backgroundColor="#F0F0F0";>';
                        output += '<td>';
                        if (msg[i].website != ''){ output += '<a href = ' + msg[i].website + ' target = "_blank">' + msg[i].name + '</a></td>';}
                        else output += msg[i].name + '</td>';
                        output += '<td class="description">' + msg[i].description + '</td>';
                        output += '<td><input type="button" onclick=' + submit() + ' value=' + msg[i].id + '></td></tr>'; // Here is where I'd like to put in a clickable button 
                    }
                    $("#content").html(output);
                    $("#myTable").trigger("update");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

If I make `submit()` simply `alert("hello")` it runs when the page is loaded for every instance of the `onclick` call to `submit()`. Could someone please explain to me how to make submit only get called when its button is clicked and not on page load. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it... the button should call a `submit` function when it's pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign `submit()` to the button's `onclick`, but you are actually calling the function when you generate the string `output`.  It needs to be in quotes inside the string, not concatenated in.

```
 output += '<td><input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="' + msg[i].id + '"></td></tr>';
 //----------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A better strategy would be to leave out the `onclick` attribute entirely, and use jQuery's `.on()` to dynamically assign the method. It is often considered a better practice to bind events dynamically rather than hard-code them into HTML attributes.

```
// No onclick attribute in the string:
 output += '<td><input type="button" value="' + msg[i].id + '"></td></tr>';

// And a call to .on() in the $(document).ready()
$('input[value="'+msg[i]+'"]').on('click', function() {
  submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `submit()` call in a quoted string.  Same goes for the msg[i].id.  All values in HTML should be quoted.

```
output += '<td><input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="' + msg[i].id + '"></td></tr>';
```